# How to get the id dynamically 'React JS)?

Tags: reactjs, database

I would like to know how in a select after a map I can get the id of each element dynamically.

I would like that when I click on the generate button, there is a random code that is sent to the selected path only?

Here is my code:

```js
// this function generate a uniq random code on each click and send 
//to database, i need to know how how I can send only this code 
//to the database 
//at the value selected in the <select> and not for all values
function generate() {
        // RANDOM CODE
        var str = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5).toUpperCase();
        // REQUEST TO POST CODE ON DATABASE
        const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
        axios.post(url, {
            code_key: str
        }).then(response =>
            console.log(response)
            );
    };

    return (
        <div className="w-full h-full bg-bikeexplogray-white">
            <select id="trips">
                {trips.map(trip => (
                    // each trip has a uniq id (trip.id)
                    <option id={trip.id} key={trip.id}>
                        {trip.title}
                    </option>
                ))}
            </select>
            <button onClick={generate}>Generate</button>
        </div>
    );
```

Here is the graphical interface:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rR7R1.png)

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve. "a random code is sent to the selected path only" - what is a path in this context?\

Comment: I would like to know how I can tell my function to generate a code only for the selected value as in the picture and not for all values

Comment: I didn't get what you mean , you want to execute a function everytime you change the selection without clicking on the button generate ?

Comment: the function will generate a random code of 5 characters to unlock a path, that's why it sends a request to the database, the problem is that when I click on generate for the moment the random code is sent for all the paths. That's why I'm trying to know how I can send it only to the selected path?

Comment: All paths in the sense??? can you create a code sandbox with comments in it with expected and current scenarios

Comment: Post Edit with comments